# Incorrect image zoom in using Responsive Slider

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, slider, zooming

I am working on a website, with a responsive slider including text. The slider is working, but using tablet or mobile the image is not shown 100%. It's shown with a weird zoom in on both devices. I can't find my mistake :( Hope  you clever guys can help me !!
This is an example of the site:

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Your image elements have no width or height set. So the original dimensions of your photos are used (and cropped by the surrounding container).

Just add

```
.slide img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

to your CSS.